# output is doubling in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

could someone help me figure out why my output is doubling? As you can see in the output it is printing out zeroes for horsepower, torque, compressionRatio, fuel economy, and fuel recommended. I then made a toString to print out the correct numbers. the numbers inside the asterisks are the ones i would like to get rid of or have print out the correct strings. This project is having us use inheritance and polymorphism so I am fairly new to this. My output is:

```
engine = Hybrid 8 Cyclinders 

***horsepower = 0; torque = 0
compressionRatio = 0; fuelEconomy = 0
fuelRecommended = 0***

transmission = Electronically controlled Continuously Variable Transmission  (Standard Verison)
horsepower = 98 hp @ 5200 rpm
Fuel Recommended = 85 Octane
Compression Ratio = 13.0:1
torque = 153 lb-ft
Fuel Economy = 51 City / 48 Highway
Fuel Recommended = 85 Octane
battery  = null
```

my main class is:

```
public class AutoTest

public static void main(String[] args)
{

  Automobile automobile;

  Prius prius = new Prius("Toyota", "Prius", "Hybrid", "Automatic", "98 hp @ 5200 rpm",
        "153 lb-ft", "13.0:1", "51 City / 48 Highway", "85 Octane");

  automobile =  prius;

  System.out.println("Automobile: " + automobile);


}
}
```

Automobile is the class that gets extended:

```
public class Automobile
{
Automobile(String make, String model, String engine, String transmission,
     String horsepower, String torque, String compressionRatio, String     fuelEconomy,
     String fuelRecommended)// setting make, model, engine and transmission
  {
  setMake(make);
  setModel(model);
  setEngine(engine);
  setTransmission(transmission);
  setHorsepower(horsepower);
  setTorque(torque);
  setCompressionRatio(compressionRatio);
  setFuelEconomy(fuelEconomy);
  setFuelRecommended(fuelRecommended);

 }// end of constructor Automobile

public String getMake()
{
  return this.make;
}

public void setMake(String make)
{
  this.make = make;
}

public String getModel()
{
  return this.model;
}

public void setModel(String model)
{
  this.model = model;
}

public Engine getEngine()
{
  return this.engine;
}

public void setEngine(Engine engine)
{
  this.engine = engine;
}

public Transmission getTransmission()
{
  return this.transmission;
}

public void setTransmission(Transmission transmission)
{
  this.transmission = transmission;
}

public String getHorsepower()
{
  return this.horsepower;
} 

public void setHorsepower(String horsepower)
{
  this.horsepower = horsepower;
}

public String getTorque()
{
  return this.torque;
}

public void setTorque(String torque)
{
  this.torque = torque;
}

public String getCompressionRatio()
{
  return this.compressionRatio;
}

public void setCompressionRatio(String compressionRatio)
{
  this.compressionRatio = compressionRatio;
}

public String getFuelEconomy()
{
  return this.fuelEconomy;
}

public void setFuelEconomy(String fuelEconomy)
{
  this.fuelEconomy = fuelEconomy;
}

public String getFuelRecommended()
{
  return this.fuelRecommended;
}

public void setFuelRecommended(String fuelRecommended)
{
  this.fuelRecommended = fuelRecommended;
}

public void setEngine(String engine)// setEngine by using switch loop to
                                   // invoke the classes that extend from
                                   // engine
{
  switch (engine) {
  case "Hybrid":
     setEngine(new Hybrid());
     break;
  case "Gasoline":
     setEngine(new Gasoline());
     break;
  default:
     System.out.println("Invalid engine entry: " + engine);
  }// end of switch loop for engine
 }// end of setEngine switch loop

public void setTransmission(String transmission)// setTransmission by using a
                                               // switch loop to invoke the
                                               // classes that extend from
                                               // transmission
{
  switch (transmission) {
  case "eCVT":
     setTransmission(new Ecvt());
     break;
  case "Automatic":
     setTransmission(new Automatic());
     break;
  default:
     System.out.println("Invalid transmission entry:" + transmission);
  }// end of switch loop for transmission
 }// end of setTransmission switch loop

public String toString()
{
 return "\nmake = " + make + "; model = " + model + "\nengine = " + engine
       + "\ntransmission = " + transmission + "\nhorsepower = " + horsepower  + 
       "\nFuel Recommended = " + fuelRecommended + 
       "\nCompression Ratio = " + compressionRatio +"\ntorque = " + torque +
       "\nFuel Economy = " + fuelEconomy + "\nFuel Recommended = " +     fuelRecommended;
 }// end of String toString to print make, model, engine and transmission for
 // car

private String make;
private String model;
private Engine engine;
private Transmission transmission;
private String horsepower;
private String torque;
private String compressionRatio;
private String fuelEconomy;
private String fuelRecommended;

}// end of class Automobile
```

My prius class is:

```
 public class Prius extends Automobile
 {
 public Prius(String make, String model, String engine, String transmission,
     String horsepower, String torque, String compressionRatio,
     String fuelEconomy, String fuelRecommended)
 {
  super(make, model, engine, transmission, horsepower, torque,
        compressionRatio, fuelEconomy, fuelRecommended);
 }

 public String getBattery()
 {
  return this.battery;
 }

 public void setBattery(String battery)
 {
  this.battery = battery;
 }

 @Override
 public String toString()
 {
  return super.toString() + "\nbattery  = " + battery;
 }

 private String battery;

 }
```

My engine class looks like:

```
  public class Engine
  {
  Engine(String engineType, int numCylinders)
  {
     setNumCylinders(numCylinders);
     setEngineType(engineType);
  }

  public String getEngineType()
  {
     return this.engineType;
  }

  public void setEngineType(String engineType)
  {
     this.engineType = engineType;
  }

  public int getNumCylinders()
  {
     return numCylinders;
  }

  public void setNumCylinders(int numCylinders)
  {
     this.numCylinders = numCylinders;
  }


  public String toString()
  {
     return "" + engineType + " " + numCylinders + " Cyclinders ";
  }

  private String engineType;
  private int numCylinders;

  }
```

Comment: You should also post your `Prius` class.

Comment: … or reduce your code to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Which values are getting doubled? Please be more precise.

Comment: i added more precise questions.

Comment: have debug where exactly your flow going after System.out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure that unwanted fields belongs to class Engine

```
public void setEngine(String engine)// setEngine by using switch loop to
                                   // invoke the classes that extend from
                                   // engine
{
  switch (engine) {
  case "Hybrid":
     setEngine(new Hybrid());
     break;
  case "Gasoline":
     setEngine(new Gasoline());
     break;
  default:
     System.out.println("Invalid engine entry: " + engine);
  }// end of switch loop for engine
 }// end of setEngine switch loop
```

This allocates engine with default / not initialized parameters and they are printed by toString() method of automobile

toString method was called like this engines and transmision methods toString() were invoked

```
public String toString()
{
 return "\nmake = " + make + "; model = " + model + "\nengine = " + engine.toString()
       + "\ntransmission = " + transmission.toString() + "\nhorsepower = " + horsepower  + 
       "\nFuel Recommended = " + fuelRecommended + 
       "\nCompression Ratio = " + compressionRatio +"\ntorque = " + torque +
       "\nFuel Economy = " + fuelEconomy + "\nFuel Recommended = " +     fuelRecommended;
 }// end of String toString to print make, model, engine and transmission for
 // car
```

Comment: thanks for the help Robert. I tried putting what you said in toString and it didn't work. i have added the engine class to try and help you. thanks for the help i am very confused.

Comment: Engine has Hybrid and Gasoline implementation ... The same about transmission